# Invalid token in struts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, struts-1

This is the code snippet I am using

```
if (isTokenValid(request)) 
                {
                    logger.debug("Add data to owner table");
                    System.out.println("Add data to owner table");

                    j=db.addRole(menuform);

                    if (j == 1)
                        menuform.reset(mapping, request);
                    else
                        request.setAttribute("recordModifyCount", 0);

                    message.add("recordmodify", new ActionMessage("record.insert", j));
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Token not valid Add owner");
                    logger.debug("Token not valid Add owner");

                    //message.add("recordmodify", new ActionMessage("record.insert", 0));
                    //forward=mapping.findForward("searchAllMenuPage");
                }
```

This is called when I click on add button
The first time I click It works perfectly but the second and afterwards It goes in else block i.e."Token not valid Add owner"
Please help me why it goes in else block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `saveToken()` first and Struts framework will generate a `token/key` in request/session.Next time when you make a request, you can check whether this token is valid or not.Once you called isTokenValid, you need to call `resetToken()` method as well.

```
if (isTokenValid(request)) {
.................
................
resetToken(request);
}
```

[Preventing multiple click](http://www.techfaq360.com/viewTutorial.jsp?tutorialId=62)